# Symfony Complex Value Injection

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

[Symfony 5.3]

Symfony auto-injection is pretty good, but I'm struggling with a specific portion of it.

I need to inject a value based on the current environment in a service through the services.yaml. This is quite simple using the expression syntax, but I can't seem to concat a .env variable.

What I currently have:

```
// services.yaml
parameters:
    SOME_KEY: '%env(string:SOME_KEY)%'

services:
    App\Service\MyService:
        arguments:
            $url: "@=container.get('kernel').getEnvironment() === 'prod' ? 'https://production.url.com?someKey=' ~ parameter('SOME_KEY') : 'https://sandbox.url.com?someKey=' ~ parameter('SOME_KEY')"
```

I would like to know if there is any way of removing the parameter SOME_KEY and use it directly in the string concatenation, since I don't use it anywhere else.

something like:

```
'https://production.url.com?someKey=' ~ %env(string:SOME_KEY)%
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: Why you don't set the full url as .env variable? `URL_WITH_KEY=https://...`

Comment: For the same reason I don't want the parameter: I only use this url in this service. And since I don't want to auto-inject all parameters used in the URL (there are more than just this one, unfortunately), I want to use the cleaner approach and combine them into one string, ready for use

Comment: You could hand the parameter to the service and add it to the url in the constructor.

Comment: There are more than 1 parameter. I simplified in order to make a more concise question! It is not cleanly doable to inject all variables, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @qdequippe, you should consider setting the full URL in an environment variable. You can have a `.env.prod` file that overrides the `.env` values only when in production environment. So following the logic of your ternary expression you will set the default values first as below:

```
// .env gets loaded first

SOME_KEY=some_value
URL=https://sandbox.url.com?someKey=${SOME_KEY}
```

Then set the override value to use in the production environment:

```
// .env.prod only loads when APP_ENV=prod

URL=https://production.url.com?someKey=${SOME_KEY}
```

When you define your service arguments you simply need to use the environment variable for the URL

```
// services.yaml

services:
    App\Service\MyService:
        arguments:
            $url: '%env(string:URL)%'
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#env-file-syntax
https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#overriding-environment-values-via-env-local

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I thought about this but, for the same reason I want to remove the parameters entry (I don't use this URL anywhere else), I didn't do it. That is why I'm trying to directly concat the env.